# Объединение нескольких объектов в группы в C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Я хочу объединить несколько pictureBox в одну группу, чтобы не писать условие для каждого объекта в С#. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

1) Самый логичный способ разместить на форме контрол `Panel`, а уже в него помещать нужные вам `PictureBox`. Чтоб работать с этими `PictureBox` как с коллекцией можно сделать следующее:

```
//когда в панеле нет никаких других контролов
List<PictureBox> pbs = panel1.Controls.Cast<PictureBox>().ToList();

//когда в панеле есть еще какие-то другие контролы
List<PictureBox> pbs1 = panel1.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToList();
```

2) Если вы по каким-то причинам не желаете использовать `Panel`, или `GroupBox`, и размещаете `PictureBox`-ы прямо на форме рядом с другими контролами.

```
List<PictureBox> pbs = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToList();
```